# AngularJS: "Controller as" syntax and directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I can't get one of my directives to work after refactoring my AngularJS code to use the "controller as" syntax.

Old working code ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HoffZ/kdL2ubpy/)):

```
<div ng-app='MyModule'>
    <div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl'>
        <input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected"/>
        selected = {{selected}}
    </div>        
</div>
```

JS:

```
function DefaultCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie"];
}

angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    };
});
```

Here is my non-working (autocomplete suggestions do not appear) version with "controller as" ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HoffZ/cnve0jbh/)):

```
<div ng-app='MyModule'>
    <div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl as ctrl'>
        <input auto-complete ui-items="ctrl.names" ng-model="ctrl.selected"/>
        selected = {{ctrl.selected}}
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function DefaultCtrl() {
    this.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie"];
}

angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    };
});
```

Comment: Where do you register your controller in angular? I'm missing somthing like "angular.module('MyModule', [])
  .controller('DefaultCtrl', DefaultCtrl);"

Comment: @John if that was the case, the original code wouldn't work as well. So it's clearly written, but OP chose not to show it here because it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Shomz you're right, I'm sorry.

Comment: @HoffZ did you check you're access to scope? I think you're doing something like scope["ctrl.names"] instead of scope["ctrl"]["names"]?

Comment: @John No need to be sorry. :) And yes, your second comment is exactly what's wrong with the code (wrote a similar answer at about the same time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to be with this line:

```
source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
```

which becomes:

```
source: scope['ctrl.names'],
```

which I see why could become problematic if used with object notation.

---

The fix was to avoid it like this:

```
source: scope.ctrl[iAttrs.uiItems], // "controller as" lets us have scope namespaces
```

and changing the attribute name:

```
ui-items="names"
```

---

See the whole thing here: http://jsfiddle.net/cnve0jbh/2/

Comment: Or better, declare uiItems as a directive scope element (`scope: {uiItems: '='}`), and thus pass the array itself instead of passing the name of the array. http://jsfiddle.net/kq1z83yk/1/

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by @Shomz the problem is how you try to access `ctrl.names`. You usually don't want to access the scope like that. Two alternatives:

- Use an isolated scope:

  ```
  .directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return {
      scope: {
             items: '=uiItems'
           },
      link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
              iElement.autocomplete({
              source: items,
  ```
- Use the `$parse` service:

  ```
  .directive('autoComplete', function($timeout, $parse) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
              iElement.autocomplete({
                source: $parse(iAttrs.uiItems)(scope),
  ```

Answer (score 1):

'Controller As' syntax is just a syntactic sugar over $scope approach to define view model.
It just creates an property in the $scope object itself. If you do ng-controller = "MainCtrl as main", it just creates a property main in the $scope object, which is same as the Controller function object.

so in the scope object of link function it can be accessed as $scope.main

As pointed out above, you can use the $parse service or you can use $eval service like this (which internally uses $parse) -

iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope.$eval(iAttrs.uiItems),